# Java : Get computer Spec via computer-name

Tags: java

is there a way to get specs of a computer using Java just by giving the computer name.

cause i dont want to get only the specs of the pc that the app is currently running on.

Is it possible to get it remotely?

Comment: It doesn't matter what language you use, you can't get "specs", if you mean things like what OS it runs or what CPU it has.

Comment: I think it might be better to define what your actual requirements are-- GargantuChet has given some indication of a couple of methods for getting machine specs, but not "just by giving the computer name", and you've hinted that these might help you do what you need to do. So, what is it that you Actually Need To Do?

Comment: i think its possible using VBScript, i heard someone did it.

Answer (score 1):

If the remove system is running Windows, and you have the appropriate privileges, you may be able to retrieve the information you want using a WMI library.

There's a comparison of Java WMI libraries http://www.vijaykandy.com/2009/09/windows-management-instrumentation-wmi-from-java/.

WMI is "Windows Management Instrumentation", and allows you to query remote Windows systems and perform certain management functions.

If you take this route, [Scriptomatic](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?DisplayLang=en&id=12028) is a great tool for browsing WMI classes.

Comment: thanks im looking into this one right now. something tells me that this is going to be bloody.

Comment: It could be. If you're writing something for limited use, such as taking a one-time inventory of machines on a LAN you manage, then you might be better off using Scriptomatic to generate a script that gathers what you need.

Comment: the app im writing is like an inventory manager. I need to get the specs given the computerName. Thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score -1):

No there is not.  Even if "computer name" and "spec" were well defined terms, there is no widely supported protocol to interrogate a machine for such information and if there were, good security practices would demand disabling it.